# String YYYYMM to Year Month - exasol - oracle based

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to convert column 'MONTH' string YYYYMM to YYYY MON format. example 201811 returns 2018 NOV.
I've tried with this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(MONTH_COLUMN, 4), ' ', TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(RIGHT(MONTH_COLUMN, 2), 'MM'), 'MON')) AS MONTH_NAME
  FROM DUAL;
```

I get result as I wanted but when I use it in R&V tool it sort it alphabetically and I need it chronological order.
Is there way to create it as DATE variable because when I try to put this one into TO_DATE function I get YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
select to_char(to_date(MONTH_COLUMN,'YYYYMM'),'YYYY MON') from dual;
```

Comment: This is better way. Thanks! Just can get it to work in chronological order inside R&V tool, so probably problem is in the tool. Thank you

Comment: Use ORDER BY MONTH_COLUMN in your query. That should take care of it. The column value will be displayed as YYYY MON but the selected data will be sorted by YYYYMM.